# How to iterate the jstl loop by using integervalues

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Hi here I am using jstl to loop over the content I need to convert the number in status1.noOfPages into integer and i want to use this integer in the begin value of next loop.....could anybody plz help me out....

```
<c:forEach var="status1" items="${list1}">
    <c:set var="wins" ><fmt:parseNumber type="number" value="${status1.noOfPages}" /></c:set>
    <c:forEach begin="0" end="wins" varStatus="loop">
        Index: ${status1.noOfPages}<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<fmt:parseNumber type="number" value="${status1.noOfPages}" var="beginningIndex"/>
<c:forEach begin="${beginningIndex}" ...
```

But you shouldn't have to parse anything in a JSP. Why isn't `status.noOfPages` an int to begin with? Or why don't you parse it in the controller, and provide the parsed value to the JSP?

Comment: In the server side I set that as an integer value but in jsp side while retrieving am getting as a string could u plz exp line me how to do it  ....thanks for help

Comment: A JSP is executed at server side. So if it's an integer value, at server side, it's also an integer value for your JSP. You just need `<c:forEach begin="${status1.noOfPages} ...`

Comment: @user2930535 You could parse it on the controller as well.

Comment: I've never heard a JSP "asking to parse". What is the exact and complete error message you got?